# How to add one more button in DateTimePicker of material UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui, frontend

I am using DateTimePicker in my React application.

[image]

I want to add one Clear button to the left of the Cancel Button.

```
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider, DateTimePicker } from "@material-ui/pickers";
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";

<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
            <DateTimePicker
              autoOk
              inputVariant="outlined"
              value={date}
              onChange={e =>handleSetDate(e.getTime())
              }
            />
          </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

How can I do that?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: As per documentation, it seems like `clearable` is the props you need to pass to show clear button. I have not verified at my end. Referring from docs only
https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/DatePicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [clearable prop](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/DatePicker) and set it to true.

[Working demo is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/date-time-picker-clear-issue-fix-8un20)

**Code Snippet**

```js
      <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
        <DateTimePicker
          autoOk
          label="Clearable"
          clearable
          disableFuture
          value={selectedDate}
          // onChange={handleDateChange}  //<---reset back to blank date
          onChange={(e) => { handleDateChange(e ? e : new Date()) }} //<---reset back to initial date
        />
      </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

*Just a heads up*: I had to use version 1x of `@date-io/date-fns` as I was getting some unrelated error. [See here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers/issues/1440).  Keep it in mind while playing around.

Comment: By adding the clearable property to DateTimePicker worked. Thanks

Comment: Is there a way of adding placeholder in DateTimePicker?

Comment: yes...  to add placeholder, just use `placeholder` and provide a value..... BUT to check if placeholder is properly visible do the following - 1. set initial state to null i.e. `...useState(null)` 2. remove `label` prop (if using) 3. just use placeholder prop i.e. `placeholder="my fav placeholder"`